# warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect

Tags: c, compiler-construction, warnings

i see this warning
How to do fix it?

```
Temp += (Table[i, temp3] - (MSB[i] ^ 0x1));
```

warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect

Comment: You have to tell us what you want `Table[i, temp3]` to do.

Comment: The warning is telling you that `Table[i, temp3]` is probably not what you mean, since it's equivalent to `Table[temp3]`.  If `Table` is a multi-dimensional array or array of pointers, perhaps that should be `Table[i][temp3]`?

Comment: Could you provide how Table has been defined?

Answer (score 4):

what is Table object? If it is 2-dimensional array then you should write

```
Table[i][temp3]
```

In your code

```
[i, temp3]
```

is a comma operator - it evaluates the 1st parameter (i), ignores it and returns temp3, so you can just drop i if Table is some kind of container that accepts single-index to access its objects

Comment: @user: consider accepting this answer, then.  (Click the green arrow to the left of the answer.)

Answer (score 2):

The comma operator evaluates any number of expressions from left to right, and results in the value of the right-most one.

You have a comma in `Table[i, temp3]`, which is exactly as doing `Table[temp3]`. Were you trying to do `Table[i][temp3]` to access a position in a bidimensional array?

**edit**: I'll explain some more, it may be useful for you. I won't be 100% precise, it's just to give you an idea of what's going on.

Why do you have to use two pairs of brackets to access a "cell" in your "table"? With one-dimensional arrays, `array[i]` will land you on the i-th element of the array, right? Well, with a two-dimensional array, let's call it table as you did, `table[i]` will land you on the i-th element as well. This time, though, that element is another array: the whole i-th row of the table.

So if `table[i]` is a row of the table, which is just another array, how do you access column j? Well, you have to go to `row[j]`, which is `table[i][j]`.

Multidimensional arrays in C are "arrays of arrays".

Answer (score 2):

Wrong syntax - if `Table` is a two-dimentional array use `Table[i][temp3]`.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by `i, temp3`? If `Table` is a 2D array, access element (i,temp3) with `Table[i][temp3]`.

**Edit:** Since I was slow enough to be beat by several answers, I'll add something so that my answer isn't just a duplicate of earlier ones: What does `i, temp3` really mean? Well, the C99 standard explains:

"The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void expression; there is a
sequence point after its evaluation. Then the right operand is evaluated; the result has its
type and value.97) If an attempt is made to modify the result of a comma operator or to
access it after the next sequence point, the behavior is undeﬁned."

So `Table[i, temp3]` means "evaluate i, then access element number temp3 in `Table`. Thus the compiler warns you that the i isn't doing anything (since evaluating i doesn't produce any side-effects).